# Are quantum mechanical descriptions of the same system relative to the experimenter doing the experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

In ([arXiv:1409.2454](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.2454)), page 9, Mermin states that

> *(...) fundamental QBist fact that a quantum mechanical description is always relative to the particular user of quantum mechanics who provides that description (...)*"

I don't see how this makes sense. I cannot find out a single instance where two different experimenters in the same lab give a different description (pure state assignment) to the same system.

If the above statement is worth considering, can someone provide a concrete physical example where this situation arises?

Comment: As an interpretation of quantum mechanics, QBism falls in the domain of philosophy. It is not actually part of science. So, there does not exist experimental conditions where one can study it.

Comment: what makes you think that the author is referring to different observers describing the same system using different *pure* states? That's not what I'd think reading that quote

Answer (score 1):

Just think of teleportation, where Alice teleports a pure state $\vert\psi\rangle$ known to her to Bob: After measuring, Alice would describe Bob's state as $X^aZ^b\vert\psi\rangle$, where she can determine $a$ and $b$ from their measurement outcome.  Bob, on the other hand, will describe his system as the maximally mixed state, just as before the measurement (in fact, he might not even know that Alice *did* measure her system in the first place).

Comment: I agree that there exists situations where one experimenter assigns a pure state to a system and another experimenter assigns a mixed state to the same system, as in your example. However, I think in the context of QBism, Mermin was referring to the assignment of two distinct pure states by two different experimenters for the same system at the same time, which is weird.

Comment: @ImmanuelVarun This does not become clear from your question.

Comment: I have edited the question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

As I understand QBism, it is a fundamental tenet that the observer's expectations dictate the particular description to be employed. For example two different physicists planning different measurements on a certain electron may employ different descriptions of it. Thus, all that quantum weirdness stuff is subjective.

However the majority of physicists accept that quantum weirdness is objectively established.

Comment: @glS Good call, I must have been feeling grumpy. I have cut that stuff out.